# Converting dictionary to a multi indexed dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, multi-index, defaultdict

I have a defaultdict that is constructed as below:

```
data = defaultdict(dict)
symbol_list = [
    'ETHUSDT',
    'BTCUSDT'
]
for symbol in symbol_list:
    data[symbol] = load_binance_data(c, symbol, '2021-12-23', timeframe='5m')
```

This is the axes of the dataframes stored in the dictionary as values:

```
[DatetimeIndex(['2021-12-23 00:05:00', '2021-12-23 00:10:00',
               '2021-12-23 00:15:00', '2021-12-23 00:20:00',
               '2021-12-23 00:25:00', '2021-12-23 00:30:00',
               '2021-12-23 00:35:00', '2021-12-23 00:40:00',
               '2021-12-23 00:45:00', '2021-12-23 00:50:00',
               ...
               '2021-12-24 19:05:00', '2021-12-24 19:10:00',
               '2021-12-24 19:15:00', '2021-12-24 19:20:00',
               '2021-12-24 19:25:00', '2021-12-24 19:30:00',
               '2021-12-24 19:35:00', '2021-12-24 19:40:00',
               '2021-12-24 19:45:00', '2021-12-24 19:50:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='time', length=526, freq=None), Index(['open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume'],
      dtype='object')]
```

I want to transform this dictionary to a single dataframe with multiple index as below:

```
[DatetimeIndex(['2021-12-23 00:05:00', '2021-12-23 00:10:00',
                   '2021-12-23 00:15:00', '2021-12-23 00:20:00',
                   '2021-12-23 00:25:00', '2021-12-23 00:30:00',
                   '2021-12-23 00:35:00', '2021-12-23 00:40:00',
                   '2021-12-23 00:45:00', '2021-12-23 00:50:00',
                   ...
                   '2021-12-24 19:05:00', '2021-12-24 19:10:00',
                   '2021-12-24 19:15:00', '2021-12-24 19:20:00',
                   '2021-12-24 19:25:00', '2021-12-24 19:30:00',
                   '2021-12-24 19:35:00', '2021-12-24 19:40:00',
                   '2021-12-24 19:45:00', '2021-12-24 19:50:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='time', freq=None), 
              MultiIndex([
                  ('open', 'ETHUSDT'),
                  ('open', 'BTCUSDT'),
                  ('high', 'ETHUSDT'),
                  ('high', 'BTCUSDT'),
                  ('low', 'ETHUSDT'),
                  ('low', 'BTCUSDT'),
                  ('close', 'ETHUSDT'),
                  ('close', 'BTCUSDT'),
                  ('volume', 'ETHUSDT'),
                  ('volume', 'BTCUSDT')],
           names=['Attributes', 'Symbols'])]
```

How can I do this conversion?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you have two DataFrames:

- DataFrame 1, let's call it `SYMBOL1` :

  |  | open | high | low | close | volume |
  | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
  | time |  |  |  |  |  |
  | 2021-12-23 00:05:00 | 1 | 3 | 5 | 7 | 9 |
  | 2021-12-23 00:10:00 | 2 | 4 | 6 | 8 | 10 |
- And DataFrame 2, let's call it `SYMBOL2` :

  |  | open | high | low | close | volume |
  | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
  | time |  |  |  |  |  |
  | 2021-12-23 00:05:00 | -1 | -3 | -5 | -7 | -9 |
  | 2021-12-23 00:10:00 | -2 | -4 | -6 | -8 | -10 |

That you're trying to turn into a DataFrame with axes of the shape you gave above. If so then here's one way to do it:

```py
import pandas as pd

# Code to Create the DataFrames in the example :
d = {'open': [1, 2], 'high': [3, 4], 'low':[5,6], 'close':[7,8], 'volume':[9,10]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(d, index=pd.DatetimeIndex(
    ['2021-12-23 00:05:00', '2021-12-23 00:10:00'], name='time'))
df2 = df1*-1

# The transformation : 
new_axis_df1 = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
    [df1.axes[1].values, ['SYMBOL1']], names=['Attributes', 'Symbols'])
new_df1 = df1.set_axis(new_axis_df1, axis='columns')

new_axis_df2 = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
    [df2.axes[1].values, ['SYMBOL2']], names=['Attributes', 'Symbols'])
new_df2 = df2.set_axis(new_axis_df2, axis='columns')

# Merging the transformed DataFrames
final_df = new_df1.merge(new_df2, on='time')

#Result : 
print(final_df.axes)
```

This produces and outputs the following DataFrame axes :

```
[DatetimeIndex(['2021-12-23 00:05:00', '2021-12-23 00:10:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='time', freq=None),
 MultiIndex([(  'open', 'SYMBOL1'),
             (  'high', 'SYMBOL1'),
             (   'low', 'SYMBOL1'),
             ( 'close', 'SYMBOL1'),
             ('volume', 'SYMBOL1'),
             (  'open', 'SYMBOL2'),
             (  'high', 'SYMBOL2'),
             (   'low', 'SYMBOL2'),
             ( 'close', 'SYMBOL2'),
             ('volume', 'SYMBOL2')],
            names=['Attributes', 'Symbols'])]
```

An example of the `final_df`, would look like this:

| Attributes | open | high | low | close | volume | open | high | low | close | volume |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Symbols | SYMBOL1 | SYMBOL1 | SYMBOL1 | SYMBOL1 | SYMBOL1 | SYMBOL2 | SYMBOL2 | SYMBOL2 | SYMBOL2 | SYMBOL2 |
| time |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2021-12-23 00:05:00 | 1 | 3 | 5 | 7 | 9 | -1 | -3 | -5 | -7 | -9 |
| 2021-12-23 00:10:00 | 2 | 4 | 6 | 8 | 10 | -2 | -4 | -6 | -8 | -10 |

Comment: Thanks for the reponse. If you print final_df.axes, you'll see that this is not the expected format mentioned in end of the question. Any other idea?

Comment: Apologies i was half asleep reading your question, I dont know how I couldn't understand these lines in the example were axes. I tried to correct my answer hope it is correct this time